# How to run processing scripts through java

Tags: javascript, processing.js

We have a requirement to create images via processing code and store 
it in a database. 
How do we call processing.js snippets from java code and pass 
arguments dynamically (e.g. in the following code, we would like to 
pass the angle in a dynamic fashion)

```
int x1 = 30, y1 = 20, x2 = 30, y2 = 180, x3 = 180, y3 = 180; 
int x = width/2, y = height/2; 
translate(x, y); 
rotate(radians(angle)); 
triangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3); 
save("triangle.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you just call the code from [Processing](http://processing.org/) itself?  I imagine it can be integrated into any Java app, since it's Java.

Comment: Since the code we intend to write doesn't have an user interface and would be run while populating all images into the database during application initialization.

Comment: I obviously don't know your system at all, so YMMV, but you can definitely, for example, run a Processing script from the command line, without the IDE in place.  See http://www.ctctlabs.com/index.php/blog/detail/how_to_use_processing_from_the_command_line_to_generate_images/ for an example.

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to go this way, [here](http://java.sun.com/products/jimi/) is an example. However I don't see much of a point going to Javascript from Java. You may consider to use [Java I/O API](http://java.sun.com/products/jimi/) instead.

Comment: We intend to use processing.js to create images and use the save(..) call to save the image in the file system. What we are looking for is to call this javascript function from a java code and automate this. Based on your suggestion, my understanding is that we need to use Java I/O API for image manipulation, which we don't want to do.

Comment: We would like to know if there are any wrappers provided by Processing Javascript itself to enable this bridge, so that we can make calls from Java code to generate this image.